# How to create notifications on the desktop web browser (chrome, firefox, ...)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, drupal, notifications

NodeJS is installed on my server.

I installed and configured the 4 modules below on my Drupal 8 site. When I see messages with "Private Message Messenger", I receive "jGrowl" notifications.

https://www.drupal.org/project/private_message

https://github.com/jez500/Private-Message-Messenger

https://github.com/jez500/Private-Message-NodeJS

https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs

**My question :**

How to create notifications on the desktop web browser (chrome, firefox, ...) ?

Here is the instant messenger :

[image]

Currently when the user receives a message, he receives a notification on my site. The problem is that if the user is not on the page of my site, he will not see that he has received a notfication.

[image]

**EXAMPLE:**

I have a nextcloud messaging. If I'm on another page and receive a new message, nextcloud sends a notification (sound and visual) on firefox (in my case I receive it in the ubuntu notification center).

How to do this with my site ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try the [notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications are added to browsers such as Chrome and Firefox using service workers. Check out [Push messaging sample for chrome.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/push-messaging-and-notifications)

Also check out this article on [web push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/)